# "KinesisClientLibIOException: Shard is not closed" on a DynamoDB Stream

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a DynamoDB table to which I added a Stream. I created a Lambda to process this stream and test throughput, latency, etc. After finishing my tests I deleted the lambda's trigger.

Then I proceeded to test the same table with the [Python `MultiLangDaemon` client](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-python), to compare and also see if it could pick up where the lambda left.

The Daemon starts processing shards and blows up with the exception below. Searching for it, I only found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470660/shard-shardid-000000000000-is-not-closed-this-can-happen-if-we-constructed-th), which did not apply. I tried deleting the DynamoDB table used to track the worker and have the MultiLangDaemon recreate it. Same thing happened.

Why does this happen and how can I recover without losing my data in the stream?

```
SEVERE: Caught exception:
com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.internal.KinesisClientLibIOException: Shard [shardId-00000001500614265247-3b7a2849, shardId-00000001500628985464-c896556e] is not closed. This can happen if we constructed the list of shards  while a reshard operation was in progress.
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.assertClosedShardsAreCoveredOrAbsent(ShardSyncer.java:206)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.cleanupLeasesOfFinishedShards(ShardSyncer.java:652)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.syncShardLeases(ShardSyncer.java:141)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShardSyncer.checkAndCreateLeasesForNewShards(ShardSyncer.java:88)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ShutdownTask.call(ShutdownTask.java:122)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
  at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```